# boto3, python: appending value to DynamoDB String Set

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have an object in DynamoDB:

```
{ 'UserID' : 'Hank', ConnectionList : {'con1', 'con2'} }
```

By using boto3 in lambda functions, I would like to add 'con3' to the String Set.
So far, I have been trying with the following code without success:

```
ddbClient = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = ddbClient.Table("UserInfo")
table.update_item(
    Key={
        "UserId" : 'Hank'
    },
    UpdateExpression = 
        "SET ConnectionList = list_append(ConnectionList, :i)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":i": { "S": "Something" }
    },
    ReturnValues="ALL_NEW"
)
```

However, no matter the way I try to put the information inside the String Set, it always runs error.

Comment: What is the error? Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421755/) help?

Comment: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: SS",
Thank you, but does not work. Tried several other sources before adding a new post on stackoverflow, so far, none of the solution provided work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DynamoDB: list\_append alternative for sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66421755/dynamodb-list-append-alternative-for-sets)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using the resource API, you have to use the Python data type `set` in your statement:

```py
table.update_item(
    Key={
        "UserId" : 'Hank'
    },
    UpdateExpression = 
        "ADD ConnectionList :i",
    ExpressionAttributeValues = {
        ":i": {"Something"},  # needs to be a set type
    },
    ReturnValues="ALL_NEW"
)
```

Comment: It now returns: Incorrect operand type for operator or function; operator or function: list_append, operand type: SS",

Comment: I suggest you take a closer look at my answer on the question I linked to earlier and try to see again if it does what you want.

Comment: I've updated the code and now it's basically identical, which makes this a duplicate.

Comment: table.update_item(
    Key={
        "UserId" : 'Hank'
    },
    UpdateExpression="ADD ConnectionList :set_value",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ":set_value": {'newitem'},  # needs to be a set type
    }
)

with this works!